# Why doesn't my catch code get executed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2012

Have a C++ application, VS2012, which looks something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    try{
        //Stuff
    }
    catch(exception& e){
       std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  
    }   

    int b;
    cin >> b;

    return 0;
}
```

- If I run in Debug mode, works fine.
- If I run in Release mode, works fine.
- If I run in F5+ ctrl the application crashes AND my catch statement is not executed.

If I go to Debug->Exceptions the tick box for C++ exceptions is not ticked and user-handled box is ticked for C++ exceptions? So I am expecting my catch statement to get executed.

I dont understand why my catch statement doesn't get executed.....

(Also don't get why code runs in release mode, but doesn't run in f5+ctrl mode)

Comment: Well... what exactly happens in `//Stuff`?  Perhaps you're relying on an exception being generated by iterator bounds checking or something that doesn't exist in a release build.

Comment: @paddy something to do with a hash (unordered_map). Unfortunately cant really tell much :s

Answer (score 2):

C++ exception mechanism is not supposed to catch "crashes" in your program. "Crashes" in your code compiled by Visual Studio generate so called *structured exceptions*, processed by `__try - __except - __finally` mechanism. They are completely independent from C++ exceptions. Normally, they will not be caught by C++ exception handlers (i.e. by `catch`).

If you want to intercept structured exceptions through C++ `try - catch` exception handling mechanism, you have to compile your code in `/EHa` mode (which might incur noticeable performance overhead). Within the IDE this is controlled through project setting `C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ exceptions`. However, structured exceptions will not be compatible with `std::exception` type, so your `catch(exception& e)` still won't intercept them. You will have to catch them with `catch (...)` and then figure out what happened using alternative means.

Better yet, if you really have to do that and you want to write your code in terms of `std::exception`, you can manually translate structured exceptions to C++ exceptions by installing a translator function through [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).